# Get Android's Constants on IDE , like View.VISIBLE = 0;

Tags: android, netbeans

How do I get Android's Constants on IDE , like `View.VISIBLE = 0;`
I have following method invocation : `input2.setInputType( *int* );`
How do I get all possible constants for this method?  I am using Netbeans IDE.
So I will know which Constants to use.

Thank YOU!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29

Comment: Yes, RTFMs should work as well, but I would like to use features of IDE since I found there is also very good features, like code completion and so forth. So may be that constant also may be easily found.

Comment: I use eclips, and it provides what you saying.